# Custom Filter for Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to make a custom filter in Active Admin page which goes 3 level deep in my Model function.

Workout Model

```
has_many: :workout_weeks
```

Workout Week Model

```
has_many: :workout_days
belongs_to: :workout
```

Workout Day Model

```
has_many: :workout_exercises
belongs_to: :workout_week
```

Workout Exercise Model

```
belongs_to: :workout_day
```

I want to write a custom filter in Workout Exercise Model's Active Admin Page which will sort `Workout Exercise` that belongs to a particular `Workout`

Comment: **which will sort Workout Exercise that belongs to a particular Workou** - what exactly do you need?

Comment: I want a filter:workout in Workout Exercise's Active Admin Page

Comment: please let me know, if my answer helped

Comment: nopes ........................................... :(

Comment: what is the problem? comment under my answer and I'll edit it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have `name` attribute in `workouts` table.

To have a dropdown selecton go with following:

```
filter :workout_name, as: :select, collection: -> { Workout.pluck(:id, :name) }
```

Or, if you need a search box:

```
filter :workout_name_eq, as: :string, label: 'Your label'
```

Under the hood AA is using [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) for filtering/searching, so consider taking a look into documentation for more info on how to build something advanced stuff.